# CSS link stays highlighted on mouseout

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've got a CSS drop down menu on a site I'm working one, and I've come across a little hitch. The drop down menu's work fine, but on one particular menu there are sub-categories that branch out to the side, these menus work fine until I mouseover the last-child of the links. Once the last-child has been moused-over it stays highlighted as if the mouse is still over it, this then proceeds to happen with the rest of the links within that list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://andy-burns.co.uk/underconstruction to view the problem and source code.

Comment: `Posted on 3/1/2391 by Andrew Burns` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's reflects on (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) - Chrome/21.0.1180.89

it is to do with this css:

```
li {
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
```

if `inline` is changed then the issue is not reproduced.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I removed that section of CSS now and it works perfectly, that was something I had put in before and forgotten about. I should have checked my code a little more thoroughly, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What browser and OS are you using, I just checked on with Chrome, Safari and FF on a Mac and could not reproduce the issue

Comment: it's reflects on (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) - Chrome/21.0.1180.89.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Windows 7, I've solved it now though, was down to my own stupidity leaving a CSS block at the bottom of my code.